# how do i know on which level of search am i using BFS (Breadth-first search)?

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

So this is the algorithm im using , i want to know on which level of depth am i using BFS

```
void bfs(int n)
 {

   vis[n]=1; //marks n visited
   d=0;
   while(!adj[n].empty()) //adj is the array containing the adjacency lists
   {if( !(vis[adj[n].front()]))
    {
      q.push(adj[n].front());  //q is the queue 
    }
    adj[n].pop_front();
   }
 if(!q.empty()){
   n=q.front();
   cout<<n<< "->";
   q.pop();
   bfs(n); 
    }
 }
```

what can i do?

Comment: Just pass along an extra `depth` parameter. In initial call to `bfs`, pass 0. In a recursive call, pass `depth + 1`. Thus: `void bfs(int n, int depth) { ... bfs(n, depth + 1); ... }`

Answer (score 1):

In order to know what depth you are now, you should add in consideration additional array *depth*. 
*depth* size is equal to number of vertices in graph and contains depths of each vertice, counting from the vertice where you start your BFS. When traversing through the childs of parent you should put 
*depth*[child] = *depth*[parent] + 1